# Undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monologue

I'm using monologue engine to creata a blog. I follow the readme file at https://github.com/jipiboily/monologue to config my app and database.

When i try to create a new article using monologue interface i get this error: undefined method 'year' for nil:NilClass.

Someone does know how to fix it?

Complete log file:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass):
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:290:in `parse'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/string/zones.rb:9:in `in_time_zone'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/time_zone_conversion.rb:37:in `published_at='
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `public_send'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:45:in `_assign_attribute'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:32:in `block in assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `each'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:26:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:452:in `init_attributes'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
monologue (0.4.1) app/controllers/monologue/admin/posts_controller.rb:24:in `create'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Paste here some code!

Comment: it would be better if you post error log here to get quick answers.

Comment: Advice. It says its calling the method on a nil class. This means there is no object. Ensure there is an object.

Comment: Post your `create` action.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved using ruby 2.1.2.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a bug with rails, the fix is to update Rails as you can see in this commit

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e88da370f190cabd1e9750c5b3531735950ab415